# Объясните, что происходит в этой строчке

Tags: java, byte

```
int s = S(8-i, (byte)(x&0x3F));
```

А конкретно, что означает `x&0x3F`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполняется операция "побитовое и" между переменной "х" и числом 0x3F (63 в десятичной системе)

Answer (score 2):

(byte)(x&0x3F) - "Фильтруются" правые 6 бит переменной х. Поскольку 0х3F это 00111111 в двоичном представлении, результатом этой операции будет 1 байт со "значимыми" 6 битами.
Например, если х имеет тип int и имеет значение 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111, то (x&0x3F) вернет 00000000 00000000 00000000 00111111. Приведение же к байту обрежет левые 24 бита и получится  00111111.